How to overwrite the default tailwind focus ring on Firefox?
Tailwind gives a default blue ring to focused elements.
I'm trying to change its color but without success, it's like the default is taking over custom rules.
https://play.tailwindcss.com/52qikegG9a
Update: after some trials, removing the outline works but changing it's color resets the ring to its default current without taking into account the custom ring color:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/ejozMHzJVQ

From this tailwind issue, with Firefox it actually needs to set the outline-style property when also setting the outline-color.
So it needs to explicitly add the tailwind class focus:outline as seen here https://play.tailwindcss.com/R6HQKqbo3L

A ring is a box-shadow. What you're seeing is an outline. You'd need to add outline-none.

That removes it but I might misundnrstand something since when I re-add it with an other color on focus, it doesn't render like the default one : https://play.tailwindcss.com/CV3viCleaw.
Or are thre both outline and ring on the default and outline-none also removes the ring's box-shadow ?

And adding a red ring shows nothing : https://play.tailwindcss.com/JPbLnHqz1Q

You need a focus:ring on the element.
There's a lot of defaults the browser has. In Chrome Devtools if you inspect the element, click :hov then :focus-visible you can see the styles that are being applied.
You really have to dig through the style panel.

That's what I'm doing here https://play.tailwindcss.com/ntru9rteOa, with Firefox. But without success. I see however it uses a --tw-shadow-colored variable that is undefined.

You're doing some weird things in the CSS tab that are hiding errors. I don't think you want to do @layer base { @tailwind base } as @tailwind base is the @layer base and it reordeds the layers.

Yeah right I tried to work it from here and forgot to remove it, sorry. It works as expected now, thanks for your help https://play.tailwindcss.com/jM6lqFfRwa. Edit: a strange thing remains is that the outline seems unable to change color : https://play.tailwindcss.com/Z7QKyTQzgp
